# How to choose a specific between several similar div

Tags: css

I have a problem, I have 5 div with the same class, it is like that:

```
div > form > div.prdctfltr_filter_wrapper.prdctfltr_columns_1 > div > div > div.prdctfltr_add_scroll.prdctfltr_max_height.prdctfltr_down
```

I try to add `nth-child(1)`, but it seems I use it in wrong way:

```
div > form > div.prdctfltr_filter_wrapper.prdctfltr_columns_1 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.prdctfltr_add_scroll.prdctfltr_max_height.prdctfltr_down
```

I want to apply a style only on the first one, not all 5. How can I choose the first one?

UPDATE: add HTML tag

the style that I want to choose is the first:

```
<div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="max-height: 120px; display: block;">
```

```html
<div class="prdctfltr_filter_inner">

  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_single prdctfltr_merge_terms prdctfltr_inline prdctfltr_text" data-filter="product_cat">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="max-height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_active prdctfltr_ft_ham"><input type="checkbox" value="ham" checked=""><span>All Hams</span></label> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e78c9f6 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 23;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Leg Type         <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 78px;display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_back-leg"><input type="checkbox" value="back-leg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Jamón (back leg)</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_shoulder-leg"><input type="checkbox" value="shoulder-leg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Paleta (shoulder leg)</span></span></label>        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e78d017 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 22;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Ham Format           <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_whole-full"><input type="checkbox" value="whole-full"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Whole - Full</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_whole-sliced"><input type="checkbox" value="whole-sliced"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Whole - Sliced</span></span></label>
        <label
          class=" prdctfltr_ft_premium-box"><input type="checkbox" value="premium-box"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Whole in Premium Box</span></span>
          </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_boneless"><input type="checkbox" value="boneless"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Boneless (full or portion)</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_sliced-individual-envelope"><input type="checkbox" value="sliced-individual-envelope"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Sliced - Individual Envelope</span></span></label>
          <label
            class=" prdctfltr_ft_special-premium-packs-sets"><input type="checkbox" value="special-premium-packs-sets"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Special Premium Packs &amp; Sets</span></span>
            </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_shavings-virutas"><input type="checkbox" value="shavings-virutas"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Shavings (virutas)</span></span></label>
            <label
              class=" prdctfltr_ft_cut-in-small-cubes"><input type="checkbox" value="cut-in-small-cubes"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Cut in small cubes (tacos)</span></span>
              </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_sal-polvo-de-jamon"><input type="checkbox" value="sal-polvo-de-jamon"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Sal de Jamón / Polvo de Jamón</span></span></label>
              <label
                class=" prdctfltr_ft_jamon-cream-spread-pate"><input type="checkbox" value="jamon-cream-spread-pate"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Jamón cream spread (paté)</span></span>
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e78d936 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 21;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Pig Race         <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_iberico-ham-black-pig"><input type="checkbox" value="iberico-ham-black-pig"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Ibérico Ham (Black Pig)</span></span></label>
        <label
          class=" prdctfltr_ft_serrano-ham-white-duroc-pig"><input type="checkbox" value="serrano-ham-white-duroc-pig"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Serrano Ham (White &amp; Duroc Pig)</span></span>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e78dfdd prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 20;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Ibérico Ham Quality          <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_100-iberico-de-bellota-pata-negra"><input type="checkbox" value="100-iberico-de-bellota-pata-negra"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">100% Ibérico acorn-fed - Pata Negra (black label)</span></span></label>
        <label
          class=" prdctfltr_ft_100-iberico-de-cebo-de-campo"><input type="checkbox" value="100-iberico-de-cebo-de-campo"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">100% Iberico de Cebo de Campo (green label)</span></span>
          </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_100-iberico-de-cebo-de-granja"><input type="checkbox" value="100-iberico-de-cebo-de-granja"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">100% Iberico de Cebo de Granja (white label)</span></span></label>
          <label
            class=" prdctfltr_ft_75-iberico-de-bellota"><input type="checkbox" value="75-iberico-de-bellota"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">75% Iberico acorn-fed (red label)</span></span>
            </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_75-iberico-de-cebo-de-campo"><input type="checkbox" value="75-iberico-de-cebo-de-campo"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">75% Iberico de Cebo de Campo (green label)</span></span></label>
            <label
              class=" prdctfltr_ft_75-iberico-de-cebo-de-granja"><input type="checkbox" value="75-iberico-de-cebo-de-granja"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">75% Iberico de Cebo de Granja (white label)</span></span>
              </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_50-iberico-de-bellota"><input type="checkbox" value="50-iberico-de-bellota"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">50% Iberico acorn-fed (red label)</span></span></label>
              <label
                class=" prdctfltr_ft_50-iberico-de-cebo-de-campo"><input type="checkbox" value="50-iberico-de-cebo-de-campo"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">50% Iberico de Cebo de Campo (green label)</span></span>
                </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_50-iberico-de-cebo-de-granja"><input type="checkbox" value="50-iberico-de-cebo-de-granja"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">50% Iberico de Cebo de Granja (white label)</span></span></label>                </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e78e891 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 19;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Serrano Ham Quality          <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_more-than-36-months"><input type="checkbox" value="more-than-36-months"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">More than 36 months</span></span></label>
        <label
          class=" prdctfltr_ft_gran-reserva"><input type="checkbox" value="gran-reserva"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Gran Reserva: 15 - 36 months</span></span>
          </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_reserva"><input type="checkbox" value="reserva"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Reserva: Minimum 12 months</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_bodega"><input type="checkbox" value="bodega"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Bodega: 9 - 12 months</span></span></label>
          <label
            class=" prdctfltr_ft_less-than-9-months"><input type="checkbox" value="less-than-9-months"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Less than 9 months</span></span>
            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e78f0a0 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 18;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title"> Appellation of Origin           <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_dehesa-de-extremadura"><input type="checkbox" value="dehesa-de-extremadura"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Ibérico - Dehesa de Extremadura</span></span></label>
        <label
          class=" prdctfltr_ft_guijuelo-salamanca"><input type="checkbox" value="guijuelo-salamanca"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Ibérico - Guijuelo (Salamanca)</span></span>
          </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_jabugo-huelva"><input type="checkbox" value="jabugo-huelva"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Ibérico - Jabugo (Huelva)</span></span></label>
          <label
            class=" prdctfltr_ft_los-pedroches-cordoba"><input type="checkbox" value="los-pedroches-cordoba"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Ibérico - Los Pedroches (Cordoba)</span></span>
            </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_serrano-jamon-serrano"><input type="checkbox" value="serrano-jamon-serrano"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Serrano - Jamón Serrano (Traditional Speciality - ETG)</span></span></label>
            <label
              class=" prdctfltr_ft_jamon-consorcio-serrano"><input type="checkbox" value="jamon-consorcio-serrano"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Serrano - Jamón Consorcio-Serrano 100% Spanish</span></span>
              </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_jamon-de-seron-almeria"><input type="checkbox" value="jamon-de-seron-almeria"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Serrano - Jamón de Serón (Almería)</span></span></label>
              <label
                class=" prdctfltr_ft_serrano-jamon-de-teruel-teruel"><input type="checkbox" value="serrano-jamon-de-teruel-teruel"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Serrano - Jamón de Teruel (Teruel)</span></span>
                </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_serrano-jamon-de-trevelez-granada"><input type="checkbox" value="serrano-jamon-de-trevelez-granada"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Serrano - Jamón de Trevélez (Granada)</span></span></label>                </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e78f935 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 17;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Producer         <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_blazquez"><input type="checkbox" value="blazquez"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Blazquez</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_carrasco"><input type="checkbox" value="carrasco"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Carrasco</span></span></label>
        <label
          class=" prdctfltr_ft_cinco-jotas"><input type="checkbox" value="cinco-jotas"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Cinco Jotas</span></span>
          </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_covad"><input type="checkbox" value="covad"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Covad</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_dehesa"><input type="checkbox" value="dehesa"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Dehesa</span></span></label>
          <label
            class=" prdctfltr_ft_extreme"><input type="checkbox" value="extreme"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Extreme</span></span>
            </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_joselito"><input type="checkbox" value="joselito"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Joselito</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_montalban"><input type="checkbox" value="montalban"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Montalban</span></span></label>            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e790100 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 16;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Ham Flavour          <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_aromatic"><input type="checkbox" value="aromatic"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Aromatic</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_intense"><input type="checkbox" value="intense"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Intense</span></span></label>
        <label
          class=" prdctfltr_ft_smooth"><input type="checkbox" value="smooth"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Smooth</span></span>
          </label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_tasty"><input type="checkbox" value="tasty"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Tasty</span></span></label> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e790754 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 15;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Boneless         <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_full-leg"><input type="checkbox" value="full-leg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Full Leg</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_partial-leg"><input type="checkbox" value="partial-leg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Partial Leg</span></span></label>        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e790cea prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 14;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Sliced - Individual Envelope         <i class="prdctfltr-up"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_sliced-by-hand"><input type="checkbox" value="sliced-by-hand"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Sliced by Hand</span></span></label><label class=" prdctfltr_ft_sliced-by-machine"><input type="checkbox" value="sliced-by-machine"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Sliced by Machine</span></span></label>        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_meta prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e790fef prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="mta_price_per_unit_spanish_club_2_10" style="z-index: 13;">
    <input name="mta_price_per_unit_spanish_club_2_10" type="hidden">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Price / Kg – Whole leg           <i class="prdctfltr-down"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height" style="height:120px;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class="prdctfltr_ft_ham_whole_leg_less_30"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><input type="checkbox" value="below-30e-per-kg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Below 30€ per kg</span></span></label>
        <label
          class="prdctfltr_ft_ham_whole_leg_less_60"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><input type="checkbox" value="30e-60e-per-kg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">30€ - 60€ per Kg</span></span>
          </label><label class="prdctfltr_ft_ham_whole_leg_more_60"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><input type="checkbox" value="above-60e-per-kg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Above 60€ per kg</span></span></label> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_meta prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e791137 prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="mta_price_per_unit_spanish_club_2_10" style="z-index: 12;">
    <input name="mta_price_per_unit_spanish_club_2_10" type="hidden">
    <div class="pf-help-title">
      <h5><span class="prdctfltr_widget_title">Price / Kg - Individual envelope         <i class="prdctfltr-down"></i>
        </span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height" style="height:120px;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class="prdctfltr_ft_ham_sliced_less_50"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><input type="checkbox" value="below-50e-per-kg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Below 50€ per kg</span></span></label><label class="prdctfltr_ft_ham_sliced_less_100"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><input type="checkbox" value="50e-100e-per-kg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">50€ - 100€ per Kg</span></span></label>
        <label
          class="prdctfltr_ft_ham_sliced_less_200"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><input type="checkbox" value="100e-200e-per-kg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">100€ - 200€ per Kg</span></span>
          </label><label class="prdctfltr_ft_ham_sliced_more_200"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><input type="checkbox" value="above-200e-per-kg"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">Above 200€ per kg</span></span></label> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prdctfltr_filter prdctfltr_product_cat prdctfltr_attributes prdctfltr_multi prdctfltr_selection pf_style_605e54e79152d prdctfltr_terms_customized prdctfltr_terms_customized_select" data-filter="product_cat" style="z-index: 11;">
    <input name="product_cat" type="hidden" value="ham">
    <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 120px; display: block;">
      <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
        <label class=" prdctfltr_ft_with-ham-holder-knife"><input type="checkbox" value="with-ham-holder-knife"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_select prdctfltr_customize"><span class="prdctfltr_customize_name">With Ham Holder &amp; Knife</span></span></label>        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Plz add the HTML also.

Comment: Thanks @ManasKhandelwal, HTML added

Comment: Is there a reason why your CSS selector is so strict? With strict I mean using the direct descendant selector `>` everywhere.

Comment: No, I just use browser selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to select the `.prdctfltr_filter` class and use the `:first-of-type` or `:first-child` selectors. `nth-of-type(0)` and `nth-child(0)` will also work and do the same.

Then select the `.prdctfltr_add_scroll` class inside the first found element.

```css
.prdctfltr_filter:first-of-type .prdctfltr_add_scroll {
  /* Your styles here */
}
```

You could make your styles a bit simpler and have the same effect, like the example above. Making your styles too specific can make your CSS a nightmare to work with.

As a rule of thumb, try not to go deeper than 3 levels `selector1 selector2 selector3 { }`.